# How to pass id (variable) from one page of html to other on clicking button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am plotting chart using highcharts on html which also has one button and on clicking button it should be able to pass the variable(cur_id+1) to other page so that it can read the json file based on variable passed.

**sample1.html**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {

 var options = {
        chart :{
                  type: 'polygon',
                  renderTo: 'chart',                                   
        },
        title: {},
        yAxis: {},
        xAxis: {},
        series: []
    };

    $.getJSON('sample1.json', function(data) {
        options.series=data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }),
    var cur_id,
    function click(id) 
    {
        cur_id=id;
        var filename="sample".cur_id."html";
        load(filename);
    }

  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<br>

 <img name="jsbutton" src="zoom-out.svg"  onclick="click(curid+1);">

</div>
</body>
```

how can this be implemented?

Comment: not relevant to highcharts. is this id coming from any series- poin of highchart ?

Answer (score 0):

you may implement this using cookie. As you are already using jQuery ,you can use jquery-cookie plugin and set your id in cookie. On next page you can get back it.

to set

```
$.cookie("curr_id", value);
```

to get

```
var id= $.cookie("curr_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

use query string for get in other page $_GET['id'];

```
cur_id=id;
    var filename="sample"+cur_id+"html?id="+cur_id;
    load(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value through query string and read the value back in the second page.

```
function click(id) 
{
    cur_id=id;
    var filename="sample.html?id=".cur_id;
    load(filename);
}
```

use the following code read the query string value

```
function getQueryStringParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? null : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url: example.com/#some_data

You can use 
    window.location.hash.substr(1); //output: some_data

Answer (score 0):

you cant use . for concat string in javascript, also I change you code to make it more simple

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {

 var options = {
        chart :{
                  type: 'polygon',
                  renderTo: 'chart',                                   
        },
        title: {},
        yAxis: {},
        xAxis: {},
        series: []
    };

    $.getJSON('sample1.json', function(data) {
        options.series=data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    })
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<br>

 <img name="jsbutton" src="zoom-out.svg"  onclick="load('sample'+cur_id+'html');">

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :-

> 1 : Either you can pass it in a url like queryString . You can also encrypt it so that your id parameter cannot be seen by the unwanted user .
>
> 2 : Or you can store it( `localStorage.setItem('id',yourVariable);`) and retrieve it `localStorage.getItem('id');` very easily using **HTML5 local storage**.

Both the options will accomplish your request . The thing is that when someone deletes the cookie/history from your browser , then the second option will not work . So better if you can go for the first one .

Example :-

for first one -

suppose your url is abc.com . On click of button , get the id and do `window.location.href="xyz.com?"+id` . Then on the next page i.e xyz.com , get this id from the url like this

```
document.URL.split('?')[1] //you will get your id here .
```

Comment: How can i get current id of page so that i can pass to next page. Any example implementing the same?

Answer (score 0):

Using localStorage Object can be an easy solution, work with both Javascript/jQuery...

```
<script>
// Check browser support

   if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // Store
        localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
        // Retrieve
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }
    </script>
```